# Picklist or Custom Metadata or Custom Object or else?

Tags: design-patterns

I have to design something like this :

User can rate 1 to 10 on Competent ,Frequency , Strength .
But each level define different based on category for example :
1 for Competent is 'do this and that bla bla'
1 for Frequency is 'here and here '

This category can be used in other object.Example objectA has field for user to select Competent,Frequency and Strength . The issue is how I should define this Category.I want to use Global picklist but where I should store the definition?If I want to store in Custom Object: will it look like this ?
The data that cover all definition for category from 1 to 10.

```
   Category Number Definition
----------------------------------------
    Competent 1      'hasjdhasjdhajsd' 
    Competent 2      'jasdjasdhajsdhs'
    Frequency 1      '3284hdjqwahd kashdkasd'
```

Something like this :
[image]

Is this the ideal design?

Comment: What i understood, you want to dependent picklist for definition ? Like if i select competent 1 then it should display  its definition ?

Comment: similar to but it will choose different base on category for example 1 for Pain has different definition .1 for Frequency has different definition.

Comment: are you planning to use vf pages for it. if yes, then create a custom setting and map it accordingly]